# Bind Dropdown using mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need help to bind drop-down values from models.

**Model.cs**

```
public class BloodGroup
{
    public BloodGroup()
    {
        ActionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    [Display(Name="Blood Group")]
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActionsList { get; set; }     
}

public class ActionType
 {
     public int GroupId { get; set; }
     public string BloodGroup { get; set; } 
 }
```

In the Controller:

```
List<ActionType> actionType = GetCourses();
bGroup.ActionsList = from action in actionType
                             select new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Text = action.BloodGroup,
                                 Value = ((int)action.GroupId).ToString(),
                                 Selected = action.BloodGroup.Equals("A+")?true:false
                             };
return view;

public List<ActionType> GetCourses()
{
        return new List<ActionType> { 
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 1, BloodGroup = "A+"}, 
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 2, BloodGroup = "B+"},
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 3, BloodGroup = "O+" },
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 4, BloodGroup = "AB+" },
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 5, BloodGroup = "A-"}, 
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 6, BloodGroup = "B-"},
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 7, BloodGroup = "O-" },
                    new ActionType () {  GroupId = 8, BloodGroup = "AB-" }
             };
  }
```

It successfully return to view. But in view when bind dropdown it throws an error.

in view

```
@model MyMVC.Models.BloodGroup

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Group, new SelectList(Model.ActionsList, "Value", "Text",true), "-- Select --")</li>
```

It returns error.

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

**Model**.ActionsList is set a Null.

I don't know why it shows null, though I inherit the model.

I need help on how to bind the SelectList value to dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a instance of `BloodGroup` class to the view in your action method, like below:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
        List<ActionType> actionType = GetCourses();
        var model = new BloodGroup()
        {
            ActionsList = (from action in actionType
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = action.BloodGroup,
                    Value = ((int) action.GroupId).ToString(),
                    Selected = action.BloodGroup.Equals("A+")
                })
        };
        return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model  BloodGroup    
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Group, Model.ActionsList,"-- Select --")
```

**Notice**

Using above example it'll show you the view without errors, but the selected item in your `downdownList` will **NOT** show correctly. For showing the selected item correctly, you need to change the type of `Grop` property to `String`, like below:

```
public class BloodGroup
{
     //
    [Display(Name = "Blood Group")]
    public string Group { get; set; } 
    //
}
```

Then use above same action method, make your view like:

```
@model  BloodGroup
@Html.DropDownList("Group", Model.ActionsList, "-- Select --")
```

Comment: I tried like this but the same error throw. The error is from View. Model is not instantiated

Comment: Lin's code seems ok, are you sure you are in the right view (that matches the action)?

Comment: hi @user2798474, I updated my answer, I think it will help you know more about DropdownList.